# Old Android devices will be supported if I use Java 8?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I'm new to Java and Android, I come from C# so I typed a lambda expression, then Android Studio marked it as an error and offers me to update the language to Java 8 if I press Alt+Enter.

If I use Java 8 language features does that mean old Android devices will not be able to run my app?

I read that Java 8 is supported since Android N (7.0), does that mean devices with android 4.0 will not be able to run my app?

Other questions asks if it's possible to use Java 8 but I want to know if it's possible to support old phones when using it.